# Node.js tinify: "Request is invalid"

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I am using `tinify.fromBuffer()` and `.toBuffer()` to compress image. I am passing in a node.js buffer that I am creating like so: `Buffer.from("data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoA [...]")` to tinify.fromBuffer.

I am doing everything as described in the official TinyPNG reference, but I am getting this error:

```
C:\programming\zoomino 6\html5help\node_modules\promise-nodeify\index.js:35
    later(() => { throw err; });
                  ^

ClientError: Request is invalid: request body requires key 'source'; request body has unknown keys 'type', 'data'. (HTTP 400/Bad request)
    at new ClientError (C:\programming\zoomino 6\html5help\node_modules\tinify\lib\tinify\Error.js:44:1)
    at Function.create (C:\programming\zoomino 6\html5help\node_modules\tinify\lib\tinify\Error.js:37:16)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\programming\zoomino 6\html5help\node_modules\tinify\lib\tinify\Client.js:86:59)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:402:35)
    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1343:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
  status: 400
}
```

Here is my code:

```js
const tinify = require("tinify")
tinify.key = "ApiKey"

const image = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoA [...]"
tinify.fromBuffer(Buffer.from(image)).toBuffer(function(error, data) {
  if(error) throw error
  console.log(data)
})
```